Permission error (EACCES) with npm after password change on macOS, unable to use sudo command
I recently changed the password for my admin account in Users & Groups on macOS and tried to install React, but I encountered the following error:
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/emilbekzoldoskan/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/d6/4d/95351bd7b1c4630fa6590049d83b56ced950f5f2fd281f27e28527249cee
npm ERR! errno EACCES

npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.

npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR! sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/emilbekzoldoskan/.npm"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
/Users/emilbekzoldoskan/.npm/_logs/2024-08-29T07_39_31_901Z-debug-0.log

To resolve this, I ran the suggested command:
sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/emilbekzoldoskan/.npm"

However, when prompted for a password, neither my new password nor the old one worked. I am aware that the terminal does not display the password when typed, but nothing I enter seems to work.
How can I fix this issue and regain access to sudo to run the command successfully?

The password it asks for is the user password of your machine. If this is a mac, it means your mac login password. If you don't remember that password, maybe try to find a way to reset it?
